# Numpy arrays behave weirdly when very big

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm using numpy to load sound files and feed them into a neural network.
I do a lot of reshaping, splitting and reassemling on some ndarrays.

My problem is that when I load only a few files (10), everything works fine. However, when I try to load a lot of files (100+), nothing works.
Loaded arrays are in wrong shape, should be (100, 1, 64000) but are (106, 64000).

Debugger shows that some values in the array are not calculated (min and max). Instead of value, the debugger shows 'ndarray too big, calculating max would slow down debugging' and nothing works.

Is there a way to ignore the implied slowdowns and make this run on my lovely giant arrays?

Comment: What code até you using?

Comment: @Dalton It's a lot of code and I don't think it would help, the problem seems to be conceptual. I can add relevant parts is necessary.

Comment: Instead, you should include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @roganjosh on it.

Comment: It's probably not the number of files, but rather characteristics (shape, etc) on one of those files.  Rather than use the debugger, include diagnostic print statements at key points in the loop.  Try to identify exactly when the assembled array shape goes wrong.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the bug. Thanks to @hpaulj for hepling me find the error - I have done that before but missed the one crucial spot. I still don't know exactly what was wrong, but it seems to have something to do with using random.shuffle on numpy arrays.

Comment: I suggest someone closes this question, I don't seem to have enough points.